# Issues with strings and char arrays in C++

Tags: c++, arrays

I'm writing a registry generator as a part of a bigger program. I'm very new in C++, but good at other programming languages like PHP.

I'll start by providing the code of the problematic function:

```
void generacionAleatoria() {
    string r_marca, r_nom, r_apellido; 
    char r_patente[6];

    int num_rand; 
    registroAuto r_auto;


    string nombres[8] = {
        "Juan", "Pedro", "Roberto", "Miguel", "Guillermo", "Emilio", "Roque", "Gustavo"
    } ; 
    string apellidos[8] = {
        "Messi", "Maradona", "Gardel", "Heredia", "Pimpinela", "Nadal", "Mascherano", "Troilo"
    };
    string marcas[12] = {
        "Volvo", "Renault", "Audi", "Ford", "Fiat", "Chevrolet", "Nissan", "Volkswagen", "Mercedes Benz", "Rolls Royce", "Delorean", "Aston Martin"
    };

    char letras_patentes[] = "ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ";
    char numeros_patentes[] = "0123456789"; 

    for (int i = 0; i < cantidad_autos; i++) {
        r_marca = marcas[rand() % (sizeof(marcas)/sizeof(marcas[0]) - 1)];
        r_nom = nombres[rand() % (sizeof(nombres)/sizeof(nombres[0]) - 1)];
        r_apellido = apellidos[rand() % (sizeof(apellidos)/sizeof(apellidos[0]) - 1)];

        for(int m = 0; m < 3; ++m) {
            r_patente[m] = letras_patentes[rand() % (sizeof(letras_patentes) - 1)];
        }   
        for(int n = 3; n < 6; n++) {
            r_patente[n] = numeros_patentes[rand() % (sizeof(numeros_patentes) - 1)];
        }

        strcpy(r_auto.patente,r_patente);
        strcpy(r_auto.marca,r_marca.c_str());   
        strcpy(r_auto.apellido,r_apellido.c_str());
        strcpy(r_auto.nom,r_nom.c_str());

        fwrite(&r_auto,sizeof(registroAuto),1,archivo);

        if (ver_variables_testeo) { 
            //cout << (i+1) << ") " << r_auto.patente<<endl;
            cout << (i+1) << ") " << r_auto.marca << " - " << r_auto.patente << " - " << r_auto.nom << " " << r_auto.apellido << endl; //Para testear
        }

    }
}
```

This creates 100 structs of the following type:

```
struct registroAuto {
    char marca[15];
    char patente[6];
    char nom[25];
    char apellido[25];
};
```

In case you're wondering, this is meant to be a registry of Uber drivers and their cars: brand, license plate, name and surname. Well, it's not really a registry, it's college homework.

The problem is that when I print out the contents of my new struct, the license plate and the name will be together, as in:

100) Fiat - KWQ293Maria - Maria Gardel

You can see by the position of the hyphens, that the license plate is now "KWQ293Maria", even though it is an array of 6 chars!

A reminder of the `cout` command:

```
cout << (i+1) << ") " << r_auto.marca << " - " << r_auto.patente << " - " << r_auto.nom << " " << r_auto.apellido << endl;
```

I did some tests, but I don't know what to do with the results.

1: commenting out the strcopy of the name fixes the issue

```
    strcpy(r_auto.patente,r_patente);
    strcpy(r_auto.marca,r_marca.c_str());   
    strcpy(r_auto.apellido,r_apellido.c_str());
    //strcpy(r_auto.nom,r_nom.c_str());
```

As you can see, this is the last of the 4 statements in my original code, so I don't know why it would affect r_auto.patente.

Can you please help me? I'm guessing there's a key concept of char array handling that I missed out on in class :-(

Comment: Without looking in depht at your code, I can say that literal strings needs one more space. It is necessary to hold the end of string (`'\0'`). In your case, `nom` must be of size 7 to hold 6 visible char (at least)

Comment: They key concept of char array handling that you are missing is that you should not use char arrays. C++ has `std::string`. Use it. Avoid buffer overflows. Avoid painful counting and calculation of buffer sizes. Just use `std::string`s. Also, your random number generation is broken.  Your random number generator will never pick the last value from the `marcas`, `nombres`, and `appelidos` arrays.

Comment: Have you tried to observe the memory contents of those char arrays through a debugger?

Comment: Thank you for your input! @Amadeus, your explanation helped a lot and fixed my random generator. However, I also had a second version of this where the user can input the information manually, and they might add more characters than needed. Is the solution just to enter a char array[100], and leave it to luck? With an array of size 7, if they use the seventh character, I'm back to my original problem.

Comment: @vic3685 `strcpy` is not good, use instead `strncpy`, which it will allow you to specify how many char it would be copied. By the way, this is more C than C++. In C++ it is better to use `std::string` exactly to minimize this kind of problem.

Comment: On the other hand, I'd love to take @Sam Varshavchick's suggestion and use normal strings. BUT... I'm copying these strings to a binary file, and when I read strings from the binary file, I just get jibberish as output and the program crashes. You can see the fwrite command in my original code...
fwrite(&r_auto,sizeof(registroAuto),1,archivo);
Is there a secret to writing or reading strings in a binary file? We only saw arrays in class, so I was trying to just stick to that, but it does seem a bit complicated in this case!

Comment: @Amadeus, I don't know how many chars will be copied. I do for the license plate in the random generator, but names can have any length. Or is there a way for me to know?

Comment: The trick to writing strings to a binary file is to write `c_str()`, or `&str[0]`, and not the `std::string` structure.

Comment: @vic3685 or you make a larger buffer, or dynamic reallocate your size, or limit the amout of char that could be copied. Better yet, a combination of them. It is up to you

Comment: Cool! I think I'm good with your help @Amadeus!

Comment: @SamVarshavchik, I would love to learn how to use strings, so I'll ask you one more thing tho. Using this format: r_auto.marca = r_marca.c_str(); I still get jibberish in the binary file. As long as I don't copy the license plate, which remains a char array, the program doesn't break, but the jibberish is still an issue. I'm I using c_str() wrong?

Comment: Probably. If you're getting garbage, you're doing something wrong, obviously. Not possible to determine what without a full [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using character arrays as *strings* they need to be terminated by a null character `'\0'`. So when you construct your number-plate you need to make the array `7` characters long.

```
struct registroAuto {
    char marca[15];
    char patente[7]; // 6 for numbers, 1 for terminator '\0'
    char nom[25];
    char apellido[25];
};
```

Same with your working variable:

```
char r_patente[7];
```

And you need to manually add the null-terminator when you create the number:

```
    for(int m = 0; m < 3; ++m) {
        r_patente[m] = letras_patentes[rand() % (sizeof(letras_patentes) - 1)];
    }
    for(int n = 3; n < 6; n++) {
        r_patente[n] = numeros_patentes[rand() % (sizeof(numeros_patentes) - 1)];
    }

    r_patente[6] = '\0'; // add the null terminator
```